# Converting curl to python: usernames and passwords

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to convert this curl statement into some python using the `requests` library.

So, I used this website: http://curl.trillworks.com/ . This worked somewhat, but it did not place my username and password into the request and I get a `<Response [401]>` every time.

CURL:

```
curl --basic -u 'myusername:mypassword' -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/items/update_stuff -d '{ "item_id":"10", "name":"NE", "price":35 }'
```

PYTHON so far:

```
data = '{ "item_id":"10", "name":"NE", "price":35 }'

requests.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/items/update_stuff', data=data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
 requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
```

Pulled from the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)